# auto incrementing primary key is not being incremented

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dexie

It seems like my auto-incrementing primary key is not being auto-incremented when I try to submit a form in two successive times. I am using Dexie as my DB wrapper. The files are below.

database (db.js)

```
const Dexie = require('dexie');

const schema = '++id, name, priority, dueDay, dueMonth, description, creationTime, &hash';

const db = new Dexie('main');

db.version(1).stores({
    items: schema,
    archives: schema,
});

db['items'].hook('creating', function (primaryKey, friend) {
    console.log(`Saving "${friend.name}" but we don't now the primary key yet ("${primaryKey}").`);
    this.onsuccess = function (primaryKey) {
      console.log(`Saved "${friend.name}" with primary key "${primaryKey}".`);
    };
    return undefined;
  });

export default db;
```

and my Main.jsx (important parts)

```
  addItem(item) {
    // Add the item to the db. This will give the item a unique primary key, returned
    // by the add operation. Assign that key to the object, and add the object to the state.
    let updatedItems = this.state.items;

    db.items.add(item)
      .then(id => {
        item.id = id;
        updatedItems.push(item);
        this.setState({
          items: updatedItems
        })
        return Promise.resolve(item.id)
      })
  }
```

and AddItem.jsx (where the form is created and submitted). `handleChange` just sets the state of that variable to what is in the input box.

```
    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.state.creationTime = new Date().getTime();
        this.props.addItem(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="add">
                    +
                </div>

                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input name="name" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input name="dueDay" type="number" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input name="dueMonth" type="number" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input name="description" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input name="priority" type="number" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
```

Below is the picture of reproducing the bug. I am logging the changes to state (that is the `name 8`, `dueDate 8`, etc). 
You can see that I first set the fields to 8 and submit successfully. The `Saving "8" but we don't know the primary key yet ("undefined")` shows that the primary key is initially undefined. After setting each field to 9, the previous line is 'Saving "9" but we don't now the primary key yet ("8")`. So it can be seen that the auto-incrementing id is not being increased after an addition. 
[image: Stacktrace]

The submission will work again after I quit and restart the application.
I have tried wrapping it in a transaction, googled, stackoverflowed, prayed to the gods, did a dance, and cried a little. Does anyone know where I am making a mistake?

Comment: ```this.state.creationTime = new Date().getTime();
        this.props.addItem(this.state);``` Somethings up with this. You are mutating state directly and also addItem you pass in this.state?

Comment: hmm you're right that's a little weird - OK so perhaps I should make an object within state that I modify, and then pass that into `this.props.addItem()`? Ill give it a try

Comment: well maybe clean up the question really think about what you are asking. I see another problem in addItem in Main.jsx  the parameter is not even used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use put instead of add.
In this case this problem solve

```
db.items.put(item)
```